# Android - Capture radio audio and save the audio into an stream buffer / file

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

With `Android`, is there a way to capture the audio from the following `radio channel`: `http://nis.stream.publicradio.org/nis.mp3` into an `stream buffer`?

Going further, my goal is to save to a file the `last 5 minutes` (maximum) of the played audio. For example, the radio could be playing the radio X seconds/minutes/hours (whatever). If the playing time is longer than 5 minutes the saved file will have the last 5 minutes. If the playing time is smaller then the saved file will have the full playing time.

I don't know if to get this result I'm gonna need to use some `data structure` like a `circular buffer`, storing `chunks of audio` on it and moving a `pointer`.

Could you give me some ideas for `Android platform`?

Comment: Are you playing this audio as well?  Easiest thing to do is just record 5 minutes worth of data from the URL...

Comment: the recording should be all the time, until the user press stop. The application doesn't know when the user will press the stop button. Only 5 minutes of audio should be recorded. That's why I say that maybe it would be interesting use some kind of circular buffer. Maybe the user press the stop button after one day or one week or one month, and I cannot record one month of audio just to get the last 5 minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: The question is, do you actually need 5 minutes of audio, or can it be 5 minutes of data?  The reason this matters is that if you need exactly 5 minutes of audio, you're going to have to decode it to properly calculate the time.  Sounds like you just need a chunk of audio though, somewhere close to 5 minutes, which you can get by just saving data for a 5-minute time period.  Start the stream, keep a buffer, and after 5 minutes, stop increasing the buffer size and circularly write to it.  Be cautious though of variable bitrate streams.

Comment: not necessary exactly 5mins, it can be 5mins or something more: 5mins3secs, or 5mins20secs, or 5mins45secs. It cannot be less than 5mins if the recording time was more than 5mins. Of course, if the user started the recording and after 3mins he stop it, then the result could be something around 3mins, in that case more or `less` than that is acceptable.

Comment: Just record 5 minutes of data then.  You'll get 5 minutes of audio, plus whatever the buffer length was at the beginning of the stream.

Comment: thanks Brad, you are right :)